# Sort Column position in datatable c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, datatable

I have Datatable with 3 columns: {`id`, `Barcode` , `Name`}

When I loop Datatable with *for* loop I get the column Id in the first then Barcode then Name.

But I need to get Id then Name then Barcode

How can I sort Column position

this is my code

```
  List<Tayf.Models.Product> dataaa = HttpContext.Current.Cache["productcache"] as List<Tayf.Models.Product>;
  DataTable dataTable;

            dataTable = transfer.ToDataTable(dataaa);
            int cols = dataTable.Columns.Count;
           for (int i = 0; i < cols; i++)
            {
             string colname=  dataTable.Columns[i].ColumnName;
            }
```

```
i=0 >>> Id
i=1 >> Barcoe 
i=2 >>> name
```

Comment: please post your code

Comment: Where is your DataTable coming from? You need to post your code to get you some suggestions

Comment: @zgood Quetion updated

Comment: @techspider Question updated

Comment: go to `Tayf.Models.Product` and change order of your fields

Comment: you may post structure of `Tayf.Models.Product` as well

Comment: @techspider Can't Do that because I use it in many other pages , I need to handle it in this piece of code

Comment: If you know which order you want them in, you know which columns there are - so simply select the column you want in the order you want them in your code. Why iterate at all. Be pragmatic.

Comment: do you care about order in other pages too?

Comment: Use a DataView. See my answer for context.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that In your `select query` you are selecting data in the sequence that you have mentioned

`select id, Barcode,Name from YourTableName`

If this is the case try to change your select statement sequence like-

`select id, Name,Barcode from YourTableName`

**Update:**
Try to use the [DataColumn.SetOrdinal](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.setordinal.aspx) method.

```
List<Tayf.Models.Product> dataaa = HttpContext.Current.Cache["productcache"] as List<Tayf.Models.Product>;
DataTable dataTable;

dataTable = transfer.ToDataTable(dataaa);
dataTable.Columns["id"].SetOrdinal(0);
dataTable.Columns["Name"].SetOrdinal(1);
dataTable.Columns["Barcode"].SetOrdinal(2);

int cols = dataTable.Columns.Count;
for (int i = 0; i < cols; i++)
{
  string colname=  dataTable.Columns[i].ColumnName;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should create a [DataView](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fdcwwhez(v=vs.110).aspx).

For example:

**dataTable** would be your DataTable

```
DataView view = new DataView(dataTable) {Sort = "Id, Name, Barcode" };
DataTable sortedTable = view.ToTable();
```